# Изменение TextArea из собственнойфункции программы в JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

не получается изменить текст в textarea , вылетает ошибка NullPointerException.

код контроллера

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent; import javafx.fxml.FXML; import javafx.scene.control.Button; import javafx.scene.control.TextArea; import javafx.scene.control.TextField; import java.io.IOException; public class CCONTROL {
    public  client_connect con;
    @FXML
    private TextField nick;
    @FXML
    private  TextArea text1;
    @FXML
    private  TextField mess;
    @FXML
    private Button But2;
    @FXML
    private Button But1;
    public String str=new String();
    @FXML //but2
    void onClickMethod2(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            con=new client_connect();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @FXML //but1
    void onClickMethod1(ActionEvent event) { //str=nick.getText()+": "+mess.getText();
        //text1.setText( str+text1.getText()+"\r\n" );
        con.tcsend( str );
    }
    public void send_message(String s){
        text1.setText( "fdg" );
       //text1.setText( s+"\r\n" );
    }
    //public void get }
```

Comment: Короче, я не смог отформатировать ваш код в редакторе. Выложите его в читаемом виде, проявите уважение к сообществу.

Comment: @ВладимирКарсанов [Вот так можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1232465/revisions)  ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ага, спасибо. Ну, я ТС вроде ответил. Даже не знаю, поможет ему это или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что контроллер и fxml-форма связаны. В форме должна быть ссылка на контроллер в самом внешнем тэге. Ссыль являет собой атрибут тэга в таком виде:

```
fx:controller="full.qualifiled.name.of.CCONTROL"
```

Затем убедитесь, что переменная text1 связана с соответствующим виджетом в этой форме. Как-то так:

```
<TextField fx:id="text1" />
```

Скорее всего пока кодили, меняли имена переменных и где-то они не согласуются.

Ну, или приложите код fxml-формы, если ничо не получается. Хоть глянем чо там.